React App Google Sign-In 403 Error: How to Fix?
I'm developing a React application with a Google Sign-In feature. When attempting to sign in with Google, I encounter a 403 error. The error message suggests that the given origin is not allowed for the given client ID, indicating a potential CORS issue. However, upon further investigation, it's unclear whether CORS is the root cause of the problem.
Details:

Error Message:
The error message states: "[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID."

The React application uses the '@react-oauth/google' library for Google Sign-In functionality.
The issue occurs specifically during the sign-in process.
I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue effectively. While the error message initially suggests a CORS issue, I'm open to exploring other potential causes and solutions. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
Tried to get the sign in with google popup. Ended up with a 403 error.
Investigation:
CORS Consideration: Initially, the error suggests a possible CORS issue, but the error message doesn't explicitly mention CORS.
Redirect URI: The redirect URI used is "http://localhost:5173/", which seems appropriate for a local development environment.
Library Configuration: Verify that the '@react-oauth/google' library is configured correctly with the appropriate client ID and other required parameters.
Debugging: Attempted debugging by checking the network requests and inspecting the error logs, but couldn't identify the exact cause.
Configuration Review: Reviewed the configuration settings, including client ID, redirect URI, and any other relevant parameters, to ensure they are correctly set up.


import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google"

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId='(cannot disclose)'>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GoogleOAuthProvider>
)



Login.jsx


import {
  IoLogInOutline
} from "react-icons/io5";
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import {
  GoogleLogin
} from '@react-oauth/google';

export default function Login({
  onLoginClick
}) {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showLogin) {
      // Delay the visibility change to trigger the transition
      setTimeout(() => setVisible(true), 10);
    } else {
      setVisible(false);
    }
  }, [showLogin]);

  const responseMessage = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    setShowLogin(false); // Hide the login page after successful login
  };

  const errorMessage = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };

  return ( <
    >
    <
    div className = "row-span-5" >
    <
    /div> <
    div className = "login row-span-1 place-self-end w-full h-20 flex justify-center items-center " >
    <
    button className = "w-full z-50 flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-400 h-12 dark:bg-slate-800 rounded-lg mx-3 font-bold"
    onClick = {
      () => setShowLogin(true)
    } >
    <
    span className = "mx-auto " > Login < /span> <
    IoLogInOutline size = {
      26
    }
    style = {
      {
        marginRight: '30px'
      }
    }
    /> <
    /button> <
    /div> {
      showLogin && ( <
        div className = {
          `fixed z-50 top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center text-center backdrop-blur-sm bg-black bg-opacity-35 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out ${visible ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'}`
        } >
        <
        div className = "bg-white dark:bg-slate-800 p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg" >
        <
        GoogleLogin onSuccess = {
          responseMessage
        }
        onError = {
          errorMessage
        }
        /> <
        button className = "mt-3 bg-gray-400 dark:bg-slate-600 rounded-lg p-2"
        onClick = {
          () => setShowLogin(false)
        } >
        Cancel <
        /button> <
        /div> <
        /div>
      )
    } <
    />
  );
}




Try running your app https
